# Who does the evil eye apply to?

Tags: yosef, ayin-hara-evil-eye

In many places in the Sources we are told that the "evil eye" does not apply to the descendants of Joseph.
For example, when Rabbi Yoḥanan boasted about his beauty:

> The Rabbis said to him: Do you not fear an evil eye?  He replied, I am of the seed of Joseph, against whom an evil eye is powerless. [Bava Metzia 84a]

What about the rest of the Jews, that is the descendants of Jacob?  Does the evil eye apply to them or not?

This *seems* to imply that it applies to all Jews:

> One who enters a city and fears the evil eye should hold the thumb of his right hand in his left hand and the thumb of his left hand in his right hand and recite the following: I, so-and-so son of so-and-so, come from the descendants of Joseph, over whom the evil eye has no dominion. [Berakhot 55b]

Comment: The last quote seems to not apply to everyone since it does not affect descendants of Joseph.

Comment: Can't you infer from R"Y's statement that it applies to everyone else?

Comment: @AlBerko -- That was my question.  If it applies to all Jews, why all these references to "Joseph" whenever the matter is raised?

Comment: This is how you try to trick it - you simply lie about your lineage.